# Variable is reset after loop

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I'm learning Java and have written a program with a for loop in it. But my variable is 0 after I print it out. Why does it get reset? This is my code:

```
Private static int number;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
    {
        number = number + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Main: " + number);
    print();
}

public static void print()
{
    System.out.println("Print: " + number);
}
```

This is the result:

> run:
>
> Main: 10
>
> Print: 0
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Those are two different variables (confusingly both called `number`). You declare a local one inside of `main` in addition to the class variable.

Comment: You have two variables called `number`. One is a static variable. One is a local variable inside `main`. You increment the local one, but you do not alter the static one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is not reset. This might be hard to grasp when you're new but by saying `int number;` you create a new variable `number` of type `int`. Also keep in mind that variables will remain in the scope where they were created and can't be used outside that scope. This means that if you initialize a variable in a while loop, it will only be available from within that while loop. The same applies to methods.

You created a variable `number` on the first line, this variable can be used by every method in your class and is set to zero by default. However, you created another variable number in your main method. This second variable only exists within your main method because that's the scope where it was created in.

Let me give you some ways to fix this:

```
Private static int number;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //By removing `int`, we reference the variable that has already been initialized
    //instead of creating a new one
    number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
    {
        number = number + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Main: " + number);
    print();
}

public static void print()
{
    System.out.println("Print: " + number);
}
```

This is a possibility if your variable doesn't have to be accessed any further:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
    {
        number = number + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Main: " + number);
    print(number);
}

//We use the created variable as a parameter
public static void print(int number)
{
    System.out.println("Print: " + number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two declarations of `number`, one as a `private static` class variable, and one as an local variable in `main`. The local variable in `main` is hiding the other variable, so the `static` variable isn't being updated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables with the same name. One is a local variable which is updated in the main loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number = 0;
    //...
}
```

The other is a static variable which is initialised to zero:

```
Private static int number;
```

(by the way, `Private` should be lowercase)

Your `print` method is using the static variable (which never changes). You can fix this by passing a parameter to the print function:

```
public static void print(int number)
{
    System.out.println("Print: " + number);
}
```

and call that from your main method like so:

```
print(number);
```

You should also remove the static variable. It's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you re-declared int number inside main() method. It is like to create new variable.

Just delete 'int' and it should work.

```
Private static int number;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
    {
        number = number + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Main: " + number);
    print();
}

public static void print()
{
    System.out.println("Print: " + number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different variables named `number`.

One is `Private static int number` and another one is inside the `main` function `int number = 0`.

I believe you wanted the static member to be changed inside your loop, thus you have to remove the declaration from the `main`  function.

```
Private static int number;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
    {
        number = number + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Main: " + number);
    print();
}

public static void print()
{
    System.out.println("Print: " + number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is to do with the scope of your variables. If you want to keep a static 'number' variable then don't include 'int' when you initialize it in the 'main' method. (see code below)

```
private static int number;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  number = 0; //you are now initialising the global static variable and not a local variable to the main method.
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
  {
    number = number + 1;
  }
  System.out.println("Main: " + number);
  print();
}

public static void print()
{
  System.out.println("Print: " + number);
}
```

OR

Personally, I prefer to avoid using global variables. you can pass 'number' in as a parameter to the 'print' method instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int number = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
  {
    number = number + 1;
  }
  System.out.println("Main: " + number);
  print(number);
}

public static void print(int number)
{
  System.out.println("Print: " + number);
}
```